# Is this Regex incorrect? No matches found

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse through a string formatted like this, except with more values:

`Key1=value,Key2=value,Key3=value,Key4=value,Key5=value,Key6=value,Key7=value`

**The Regex**

`((Key1)=(.*)),((Key2)=(.*)),((Key3)=(.*)),((Key4)=(.*)),((Key5)=(.*)),((Key6)=(.*)),((Key7)=(.*))`

In the actual string, there are about double the amount of key/values, but I'm keeping it short for brevity. I have them in parentheses so I can call them in groups. The keys I have stored as Constants, and they will always be the same. The problem is, it never finds a match which doesn't make sense (unless the Regex is wrong)

Comment: Do you need that many parentheses?  What happens when you try something much simpler like `Key1=value` ?

Comment: Still no matches by doing `String pattern = "Key1=(.*)";`

Comment: @Gray: not always true... it depends what function you're using the regex in. Speaking of which, Doctor Oreo, what code are you using to see that there's no match?

Comment: It throws an `IllegalStateException`: no matches found.

Comment: but are you using matches, split, replace, or what?

Comment: I'm using `matcher.group(1)`, etc and adding it as a variable to an object. Then, I add that object to a list....the list is empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging by your comment above, it sounds like you're creating the Pattern and Matcher objects and associating the Matcher with the target string, but you aren't actually *applying* the regex.  That's a very common mistake.  Here's the full sequence:

```
String regex = "Key1=(.*),Key2=(.*)"; // etc.
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(targetString);
// Now you have to apply the regex:
if (m.find())
{
  String value1 = m.group(1);
  String value2 = m.group(2);
  // etc.
}
```

Not only do you have to call `find()` or `matches()` (or `lookingAt()`, but nobody ever uses that one), you should always call it in an `if` or `while` statement--that is, you should make sure the regex actually *worked* before you call any methods like `group()` that require the Matcher to be in a "matched" state.

Also notice the absence of most of your parentheses.  They weren't necessary, and leaving them out makes it easier to (1) read the regex and (2) keep track of the group numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you'd do better to do:

```
String[] pairs = data.split(",");
```

Then parse the key/value pairs one at a time

Comment: Some of the items may have a comma in the value.

Comment: Then how do you distinguish them? What if one of the values contains `Key1=`?

Comment: Well, I take that back somewhat. The only one that may contain commas is the `Notes=`, and I'm not sure how to get around that. Ideas?

Comment: And from there, I would have to then use regex or do some sort of String manipulation in order to get ONLY the value, and not the key.

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong per se, but it requires a lot of backtracking which might cause the regular expression engine to bail.  I would try a split as suggested elsewhere, but if you really need to use a regular expression, try making it non-greedy.

```
((Key1)=(.*?)),((Key2)=(.*?)),((Key3)=(.*?)),((Key4)=(.*?)),((Key5)=(.*?)),((Key6)=(.*?)),((Key7)=(.*?))
```

To understand why it requires so much backtracking, understand that for

```
Key1=(.*),Key2=(.*)
```

applied to

```
Key1=x,Key2=y
```

Java's regular expression engine matches the first `(.*)` to `x,Key2=y` and then tries stripping characters off the right until it can get a match for the rest of the regular expression: `,Key2=(.*)`.  It effectively ends up asking,

1. Does `""` match `,Key2=(.*)`, no so try
2. Does `"y"` match `,Key2=(.*)`, no so try
3. Does `"=y"` match `,Key2=(.*)`, no so try
4. Does `"2=y"` match `,Key2=(.*)`, no so try
5. Does `"y2=y"` match `,Key2=(.*)`, no so try
6. Does `"ey2=y"` match `,Key2=(.*)`, no so try
7. Does `"Key2=y"` match `,Key2=(.*)`, no so try
8. Does `",Key2=y"` match `,Key2=(.*)`, yes so the first `.*` is `"x"` and the second is `"y"`.

EDIT:

In Java, the non-greedy qualifier changes things so that it starts off trying to match nothing and then building from there.

1. Does `"x,Key2=(.*)"` match `,Key2=(.*)`, no so try
2. Does `",Key2=(.*)"` match `,Key2=(.*)`, yes.

So when you've got 7 keys it doesn't need to unmatch 6 of them which involves unmatching 5 which involves unmatching 4, ....  It can do it's job in one forward pass over the input.

Comment: How is the non-greedy pattern different? In what way does it analyze the target string? How is it more effective?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is working for me...

If you are always getting an IllegalStateException, I would say that you are trying to do something like:

```
matcher.group(1);
```

without having invoked the find() method.

You need to call that method before any attempt to fetch a group (or you will be in an illegal state to call the group() method)

Give this a try:

```
    String test = "Key1=value,Key2=value,Key3=value,Key4=value,Key5=value,Key6=value,Key7=value";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((Key1)=(.*)),((Key2)=(.*)),((Key3)=(.*)),((Key4)=(.*)),((Key5)=(.*)),((Key6)=(.*)),((Key7)=(.*))");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

    matcher.find();

    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to say that there's no regex that will work for this, but it's most likely more complicated to write (and more importantly, read, for the next person that has to deal with the code) than it's worth. The closest I'm able to get with a regex is if you append a terminal comma to the string you're matching, i.e, instead of:

```
"Key1=value1,Key2=value2"
```

you would append a comma so it's:

```
"Key1=value1,Key2=value2,"
```

Then, the regex that got me the closest is: `"(?:(\\w+?)=(\\S+?),)?+"`...but this doesn't quite work if the values have commas, though.

You can try to continue tweaking that regex from there, but the problem I found is that there's a conflict in the behavior between greedy and reluctant quantifiers. You'd have to specify a capturing group for the value that is greedy with respect to commas up to the last comma prior to an non-capturing group comprised of word characters followed by the equal sign (the next value)...and this last non-capturing group would have to be optional in case you're matching the last value in the sequence, and maybe itself reluctant. Complicated.

Instead, my advice is just to split the string on `"="`. You can get away with this because presumably the values aren't allowed to contain the equal sign character.

Now you'll have a bunch of substrings, each of which that is a bunch of characters that comprise a value, the last comma in the string, followed by a key. You can easily find the last comma in each substring using `String.lastIndexOf(',')`.

Treat the first and last substrings specially (because the first one does not have a prepended value and the last one has no appended key) and you should be in business.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you always have 7, the hack-of-least resistance is

```
^Key1=(.+),Key2=(.+),Key3=(.+),Key4=(.+),Key5=(.+),Key6=(.+),Key7=(.+)$
```

Try it out at http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm

I'm pretty sure that there is a better way to parse this thing down that goes through .find() rather than .matches() which I think I would recommend as it allows you to move down the string one key=value pair at a time.  It moves you into the whole "greedy" evaluation discussion.

Answer (score 0):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems. - Jamie Zawinski

The simplest solution is the most robust.

```
final String data = "Key1=value,Key2=value,Key3=value,Key4=value,Key5=value,Key6=value,Key7=value";
final String[] pairs = data.split(",");
for (final String pair: pairs)
{
   final String[] keyValue = pair.split("=");
   final String key = keyValue[0];
   final String value = keyValue[1];
}
```

Comment: I wanted to do this originally, but one of the values will also most likely contain commas at some point. Any suggestions for this scenario?